# Angular dynamic creating table element and bind to a function

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with dynamic table creating with `ng-click`.

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.columns; j++) {
     content += '<td class="unchecked" ng-click="service.doSth()"></td>';
}
```

The problem is that `service.doSth()` is normal string literal in the output and Angular doesn't do anything.. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The standard "AngularJS way" to add repeated elements that work with `ng-click` and other things is to use an `ng-repeat`. Wherever you want these elements placed, use something along the lines of this in your HTML:

```
  <td ng-repeat="column in data.columns" class="unchecked" ng-click="service.doSth()"></td>
```